# What is .Lenovoreaper in Lenovo tablet

Tags: file-management, lenovo

In my file manager (of Lenovo tablet) i saw a hidden file with the name .Lenovoreaper when i tried to open it, they asked if I wanted to see the file through html viewer or google chrome, It is a 17 byte file
some ON THE INTERNET say it is malware some say it is of the share it application which I do not have....but I do have to say the file manager which it was in had ads and I guess share it was also used in advertising....what are your thoughts

So what is this file and what is it used for

Comment: yes I did some say its malware some say its part of the shareit app which i dont have. I just want to know whether it can access my photos videos and files on internal storage

Comment: @beeshyams I did check some say it is malware some say it is of the share it application which I do not have....but I do have to say the file manager which it was in had ads and I guess share it was also used in advertising....what are your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Security-Malware/LenovoReaper-what-is-it/td-p/2091200) and some others I’ve found, it’s something to do with the advertising experience in the ShareIt app. It’s not malware, but it should be safe to delete.

The reason it sometimes gets flagged is because of the advertising service inside of it.